# Execute Perl Script from Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, perl

Ok so i have the following script to scrape contact details from a list of urls (urls.txt). When i run the following command direct from the terminal i get the correct result

```
perl saxon-lint.pl --html --xpath 'string-join(//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])' http://url.com
```

however when i call the above command from within a script i get a "no such file or directory" result

Here is a copy of my script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read inputline
do
  //Read the url from urls.txt
  url="$(echo $inputline)"

  //execute saxon-lint to grab the contents of the XPATH from the url within urls.txt
  mydata=$("perl saxon-lint.pl --html --xpath 'string-join(//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])' $url ")

  //output the result in myfile.csv
  echo "$url,$mydata" >> myfile.csv

  //wait 4 seconds
  sleep 4

//move to the next url
done <urls.txt
```

i have tried changing the perl to ./ but get the same result

can anyone advise where i am going wrong with this please

The error that i am receiving is

```
./script2.pl: line 6: ./saxon-lint.pl --html --xpath 'string-join(//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])' http://find.icaew.com/listings/view/listing_id/20669/avonhurst-chartered-accountants : No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using absolute path.

Comment: tried but the same result

Comment: use `\ to escape the `/

Comment: how is this perl within perl as claimed in the title? This is perl within bash.

Comment: i am new to linux so you will have to excuse the terminology used

Comment: @JohnDoe can you please elaborate on your answer. Not sure how to interpret

Comment: @PowerMan2015 can you explain what each line should do? also have you tryed to give an absolute path to `myfile.csv`, like `d:\myfile.csv`?

Comment: @JohnDoe i have amended the above script to show the expected result. I have just tried changing myfile.csv to /root/saxon-lint/myfile.csv but getting the same result

Comment: What about your input file?

Comment: my input file is a text file with a url on each line. i can see the correct url being printer to the screen as it cycles through the list. Copying the executed line from the output and running works great. ./script2.pl: line 6: ./\saxon-lint.pl --html --xpath 'string-join(//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])' http://find.icaew.com/listings/view/listing_id/20669/avonhurst-chartered-accountants : No such file or directory

Comment: Can you put the full eror in your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121929/discussion-between-john-doe-and-powerman2015).

Comment: i have added the error message to the question above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't put double quotes inside the command substitution.

Not:

```
mydata=$("perl saxon-lint.pl --html --xpath 'string-join(//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])' $url ")
# .......^...........................................................................................^
```

But this:

```
mydata=$(perl saxon-lint.pl --html --xpath 'string-join(//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])' $url )
```

With the double quotes, you're instructing bash to look for a program named "perl saxon-lint.pl --html etc etc" in the path, spaces and all, and clearly no such program exists.

Comment: You probably intended to put the quotes outside the command substitution, but for variable assignments they are not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You should accept @glennjackman's answer, as that is exactly the problem.  This line:

```
mydata=$("perl saxon-lint.pl --html --xpath 'string-join(//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])' $url ")
```

is telling the shell to run this command:

```
"perl saxon-lint.pl --html --xpath 'string-join(//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2])' $url "
```

... *including the double quotes*.  If you type that with the double quotes at the shell prompt, you'll get the same "No such file or directory" error message that you're getting from your script.

A couple other notes on the script:

```
  url="$(echo $inputline)"
```

This is a roundabout way of making a second variable into a copy of the first.  A simple `url=$intputline` would work as well, but you could also just use `read url` in the first place.  Not sure why you need two variables.

```
  //output the result in myfile.csv
  echo "$url,$mydata" >> myfile.csv
```

Be aware that when passing a variable containing user-supplied input as the first argument to `echo`, you create the possibility of unexpected behavior. In this case, it's a low possibility, since a URL isn't likely to start with a `-` character, but it's good to get out of the habit; I would use `printf`.  Also, instead of appending each line inside the loop, I would just redirect the output of the loop along with the input:

```
  printf '%s,%s\n' "$url" "$mydata"
  [...]
done <urls.txt >>myfile.csv
```

If you don't expect `myfile.csv` to exist or have anything you need to keep at the top of the loop, you can change that to a single `>` and avoid the possibility of messy mixtures of output from different runs.

Comment: Yes, including them..  try typing `"ls"` with the quotes at the command line, and you'll get a directory listing. The shell doesn't distinguish between words and strings.  All quotes do is keep you from having to escape characters (including spaces). To the shell, `"ls"` and `ls` (and `'ls'` and `\ls` and `l\s` and `\l\s`...) are exactly the same thing (except the quoted versions won't trigger an alias lookup). If you try `"ls -l"`, then you'll get an error because it's looking for a command named `ls -l`, instead of looking for one named `ls` and running it with an argument of `-l`.